# How can I make text look like this?

Tags: indentation, text

My output should look like this. I know I have to use hangindent or sth., but I can't figure out how to achieve it that between the indent and the new line there is no space. When I try it with indents, I have one line space in between, otherwise it doesn't work. So how can I make text look like this?

[image: My output should exactly look like this:]

Comment: Should this be the default format of the body text or rather something like a list?

Answer (score 3):

You don't give much context, in latex you would normally get such a paragraph shape as part of a list, but if it's just text you can set a negative `\parindent`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\leftskip=1cm
\parindent=-1cm

asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy
asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy
asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy

asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy
asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy
asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy

asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy
asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy
asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfyy

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: Somehow there is always an indent in the first line when I try this. In an empty document it works but in my full document there is an indent I can't get away...

Comment: @GereonRath Dollars to donuts, you're coming after a section heading?